# Angular.js configuring ui-router child-states from multiple modules

Tags: angularjs, module, state, angular-ui, ngboilerplate

I'd like to implement a setup where i can define a "root state" in the main module, and then add child states in other modules. This, because i need the root state to resolve before i can go to the child state.

Apparently, this should be possible according to this FAQ:
[How to: Configure ui-router from multiple modules](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-ui-router-from-multiple-modules)

For me it doesn't work:
**Error** Uncaught Error: No such state 'app' from ngBoilerplate.foo

Here is what i have:

**app.js**

```
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate', [
  'templates-app',
  'templates-common',
  'ui.state',
  'ui.route',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ngBoilerplate.library'
])
.config( function myAppConfig ( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider ) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            views:{
                "main":{
                    controller:"AppCtrl"
                }
            },
            resolve:{
                Auth:function(Auth){
                    return new Auth();
                }
            }
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/foo','/foo/tile');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( '/foo' );
})
.factory('Auth', ['$timeout','$q', function ($timeout,$q) {
    return function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log('before resolve');
        $timeout(function () {
            console.log('at resolve');
            deferred.resolve();
        }, 2000);

        return deferred.promise;

    };
}])
.run(function run( $rootScope, $state, $stateParams ) {
    console.log('greetings from run');

    $state.transitionTo('app');
})
.controller( 'AppCtrl', function AppCtrl ( $scope, Auth ) {
    console.log('greetings from AppCtrl');
});
```

**foo.js**

```
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate.foo', ['ui.state'])

.config(function config( $stateProvider ) {
  $stateProvider
      .state( 'app.foo', {
        url: '/foo/:type',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller:'FooCtrl',
                templateUrl: function(stateParams) { /* stuff is going on in here*/ }
            }
        }
      });
})
.controller( 'FooCtrl', function FooCtrl( $scope ) {
  console.log('deferred foo');
});
```

How do i make this work or what other approaches could i take to have something global resolved before every state (without defining a resolve on each state)?

Comment: I am trying to do the exact same thing, and I think I know the issue. I believe it's just a limitation with `$stateProvider`.

The scenario you (and I) have is the module that defines the root state (in this scenario state `app` in module 'ngBoilerplate`) requires another module (in this case `ngBoilerplate.foo`) that defines a state that is a child of the said root state (i.e. `app.foo`). All of the first module's (`ngBoilerplate`) dependencies need to be resolved first (which includes running all their `.config`s to be run) before it runs its own `.config`.

Comment: So if `$stateProvider` could only allow for the defining of child states, even if the parent state hasn't yet been defined, and instead throw a fit after the config stage if there is a child state with no parent state defined.

Comment: Have you tried @Sydney answer below?

Comment: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VmwevHcOmBrmGuQmlBgP?p=preview) to clearly demonstrate the issue I just described. In the console it will output "test config" then throw a `Uncaught Error: No such state 'app' from test` because the `$stateProvider.state('app', {...});` in the `app` module's config hasn't been run yet. Sydney's answer doesn't help with the issue at hand.

Comment: In your Plunkr I would reverse the dependency. 'test' module depends on `app` module since `app.test` state depends on `app` state. So `var module = angular.module('app', ['ui.state']);` and `var test = angular.module('test', ['app']);`, your Plunkr now complains about the missing controller which is correct.

Comment: @Sydney i made a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tEFKXno3FIkgnwUCsKaA?p=preview) with your approach. Now the app module doesn't know anything about the child-state defined in the other module.

Comment: It seems that `app` needs to depends on `test`. But doing so will introduce a dependency cycle. Could you try to set `ng-app` module to `test`? `<html ng-app="test">`

Comment: @Sydney [that](http://plnkr.co/edit/NsapRqrcDuTZoEmrgYLb?p=preview) didn't work out neither. `test` aswell as `app` is now being configured, the `app` controller is being executed, but transitioning to `app.test` fails without any further error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally chose this approach which does the job for me:

```
// add all your dependencies here and configure a root state e.g. "app"
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate', ['ui.router','templates-app',
'templates-common','etc','etc']);

// configure your child states in here, such as app.foo, app.bar etc.
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate.foo', ['ngBoilerplate']);
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate.bar', ['ngBoilerplate']);

// tie everything together so you have a static module name
// that can be used with ng-app. this module doesn't do anything more than that.
angular.module( 'app', ['ngBoilerplate.foo','ngBoilerplate.bar']);
```

and then in your app index.html

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for simple and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation the `feature1` module depends on the `application` module. Try

```
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate.foo', ['ngBoilerplate'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would of just commented but i do not have the rep. I know this is old but i had the same problem and came across this. One thing i am confused about is in app.js you do not import "ngBoilerplate.foo" but ngBoilerplate.library instead. I had the same problem and my solution was to inject sub modules into the top module instead of their parent.

My structure was module('ngBoilerplate'), module('ngBoilerplate.foo') and module('ngBoilerplate.foo.bar')'. I was injecting ngBoilerplate.foo.bar into ngBoilerplate.foo and the $stateProvider was failing. I needed to inject ngBoilerplate.foo.bar into top level ngBoilerplate.

I thought i would put this here in case anyone else sees this. The error i had was Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigable' of undefined from ngBoilerplate.foo